# How do I put a space between every data got from the FOR LOOP

Tags: python, for-loop, web-scraping

I am a new learner in python and was trying to get some data from 2 webpages using Beautiful Soup and FOR LOOP to loop over it and print that.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen as Ureq


url = ["https://www.sullinscorp.com/product/?pn=EMC31DRYS-S734&toggle=in","https://www.sullinscorp.com/product/?pn=PBC10SBBN&toggle=in"]

for i in url:
    a = Ureq(i)

    page_html = a.read()
    psoup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

    c = psoup.find_all("tr")
    for item in c:
        print(item.text)
```

From the above code you can see that I am able to get output from both the webpages in a sequence but I want to insert a space or some characters between the data of both the webpages to differentiate them. For that I used my little brain and put a print(------) command in the last of my code. But what it does it just printing the character line after every row.

```
c = psoup.find_all("tr")
    for item in c:
        print(item.text)
        print("------")
```

Any suggestion on that.

Comment: Could you add 3 lines with what the expected output would look like please?

Comment: Hi Celius. Right now I m getting o/p like:
1. ABC
2. DBG
3. GHT
1. RFG
2. RTY
3. FDF

But I want to get in this manner:

1. ABC
2. DBG
3. GHT
-------
1. RFG
2. RTY
3. FDF

Hope you got my point.

Comment: put you `print("====")` inside the outer loop and not the inner loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, the separator lines should be placed in the first for loop, which iterates over each url and not the text. Therefore you need to remove one indentation level:

```
for i in url:
    a = Ureq(i)

    page_html = a.read()
    psoup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

    c = psoup.find_all("tr")
    for item in c:
        print(item.text)
    print("------")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#...
c.psoup.find_all("tr")
for item in c:
    print(item.text)
print("-----") #this line executed once the first url treated, before the second
```